# How to select row in TableView (qml) from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I try to select single row in my TableView using c++ function. In documentation I found  [property "selection"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#selection-prop) but when I try to use this in my code I get an error.

First question. How use this property in my QML code? This way don't work because of error : Invalid property assignment: "selection" is a read-only property

```
    TableView{
     ....
     selection.select(0)
    }
```

And my second question. How change this property by c++? I know that I have to use setProperty() method but as a second argument will be function: select(0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#selection-prop):

```
tableview.selection.select(0)       // select row index 0

tableview.selection.select(1, 3)    // select row indexes 1, 2 and 3

tableview.selection.deselect(0, 1)  // deselects row index 0 and 1

tableview.selection.deselect(2)     // deselects row index 2
```

You can't do it from the definition of TableView. You have to do it from JavaScript later on. Assign an ID to your TableView and using that id, select appropriate row using JavaScript.

**EDIT:**

To do it from C++, you first need to get a handle on that object. The best way to do it is to assign `objectName` property to that element and then look for it using `QObject::findChild()`. Once you've acquired the pointer to your TableView, you can invoke its methods, as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html). Actually, you'll first need to get its `selection` property, then invoke its (the `selection`'s) `select()` method.